# Init form in ionic 4 return an exception

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have this .ts :

```
...
public storage?: StorageInterface;

public form: FormGroup;

constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    public storageService: StorageService,
    public router: Router
) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.initStorage();
}

initStorage() {
    this.storageService.getStorage().then((data: StorageInterface) => {
        this.storage = data;
        this.initForm();
    });
}

initForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        checkbox: this.fb.control(true, [])
    });
} 
...
```

The html :

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" [formGroup]="form">
    <ion-toggle [name]="checkbox" formControlName="checkbox" (ionChange)="stateChange($event)"></ion-toggle>
</form>
```

I get the message `ERROR TypeError: "this.form is undefined"`. Very strange because if I put `initForm()` in `ngOnInit()` it works fine.

Have you an idea ? I need to put initForm() in initStorage() because I need some data from this.storage to populate my form

Comment: first you should call **initForm() ** in **ngOnInit()**

Answer (score 0):

You're using the form before it's initialized, that's why the error says `this.form` is undefined. I suggest initializing the form before the view renders, e.g in `ngOnInit` or in the constructor.